# Size of the universe 13 billion years ago

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, estimation, big-bang

When wee look at the sky in opposite directions, we can see early galaxies that were formed about 13 billion years ago. At that time, the distance between two such galaxies at the opposite ends of the universe was only about 45 million light years. That implies that most of the billions of galaxies that we see today were inside such small volume. Is my conclusion correct?

If it is correct, I cannot make sense of it. If we were able to pack all galaxies in such volume, assuming a diameter per galaxy of 100000 light years, then we could only fit 125 million galaxies there. How is this possible? Were galaxies much more dense and smaller then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first galaxies formed at redshifts of 10-20. Such galaxies are now at proper distances (comoving radial distance) of 30-35 billion light years and thus would be at proper distances of 1.7-3 billion light years when they formed.

Thus I think the premise of your question is flawed; although the first galaxies probably were considerably smaller than the big spirals and ellipticals in the present universe that are likely built from many mergers.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks a lot. I am going to wait to see if someone disagrees with your numbers before accepting it.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny where did the 45 million light years come from? Would that be at the redshift of the CMB? Note that the size of the observable universe then is not the same as it is now.

Comment: I could not find the link again, but I did not use any equation, only what was mentioned in some article. it was likely unreliable, or, most likely, I misunderstood something. Thanks for you answer